# Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS - What kernel version does it come with?

Tags: server, 18.04

I am currently considering installing Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS on a new box that will be very I/O intensive (multiple Samsung 970 Pros used for a crap-ton of random R/W I/O), instead of the usual CentOs (with its ancient 3.x series stock Linux Kernel). I was wondering what stock kernel Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS will be packaged with?

I know that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS itself has a pretty recent kernel and am wondering what the Ubuntu team chose for the Server release.

Answer (score 14):

The same kernel. It's the same distribution.

The only difference between the server media and the desktop media is the installer, and the *default* set of packages. The repositories and software versions is identical.

From [Ubuntu Server FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#What.27s_the_difference_between_desktop_and_server.3F):

> Before 12.04, Ubuntu server installs a server-optimized kernel by default. Since 12.04, there is no difference in kernel between Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server since linux-image-server is merged into linux-image-generic

Answer (score 7):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Linux_kernel_4.15 specifies it comes with the 4.15 kernel.